# Floating forms in contact-form

Tags: css, forms, wordpress, css-float

I found a contactform plugin for wordpress that seems easy enough. Its a free plug-in so I'm sure the author wont mind me posting some of his code. I'm trying to place the text-area next to the text-fields. There is something strange going on here. When I use a negative margin the blue box just "dissapears" under the red.

```
<div id="simple-contact-form">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bald1/3c7WG/

Comment: So you are looking to put the message area directly next to the three other fields? Similar to the image shown below?

Comment: yes exactly like that...I dont know why it wont work. I´ve placed stuff next to each other before without any hassle..It seems to me that osi(below) managed to seperate the blue box from the rest..

Comment: You're going to have to play with the width percentages on your specific browser until it works. The sad truth is that all browsers interpret your code differently, this seems to be the case. To be even more clear, the percentage is located in "#simple-contact-form fieldset"

Comment: Just tried it out in firefox and it worked! You are right!
Typical...Im gonna play around with it and see what happens..Tahnk you!!

Comment: Yeah of course.. did my jsfiddle work or was it osi's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make this work cross browser you need to following css:

```
#simple-contact-form .right {
 float: right;
    width: 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}

#simple-contact-form .right fieldset {
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}


fieldset {
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

And you need to include the three textboxes inside a div with a class "right":

```
<div class="right">

        <fieldset class="scf-name">
            <label for="scf_name">Name (Required)</label>
            <input name="scf_name" id="scf_name" type="text" size="33" maxlength="99" value="" placeholder="Your name" />
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="scf-email">
            <label for="scf_email">Email (Required)</label>
            <input name="scf_email" id="scf_email" type="text" size="33" maxlength="99" value="" placeholder="Your email" />
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="scf-response">
            <label for="scf_response">1 + 1 =</label>
            <input name="scf_response" id="scf_response" type="text" size="33" maxlength="99" value="" placeholder="2" />
        </fieldset>

</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3c7WG/8/

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I would like the messagebox to appear next to the textboxes and not under them . If possible..
Aha! Now i see your image! Thats what i want!, im gonna try that. Thanks!

Comment: In the screenshot the blue box is on the left of the green boxes not under them?

Comment: Yes, in your picture it looks great but when I look at your fiddle, the blue box does not jump-up..and i got the same problem when I added the snippet to my own fiddle..

Comment: This a screenshot of the Fiddle on OSX in Chrome. What browser are you using?

Comment: Ok, I found the problem but not a solution yet. The problem is the width of the fieldset. It differs in the various browsers.

Comment: The code comes from a plugin. On the authors site: 
http://perishablepress.com/simple-basic-contact-form/
He shows the html..hope its ok to post this?

Comment: Thank you but it did not work for me...the textboxes lined-up next to each other.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42735/discussion-between-osi-and-user2915962)